# ReactJS and CSS media queries don't seem to be working correctly?

Tags: css, reactjs

I made a website, and it was working fine. I wasn't sure how to work with create-react-app so i messed up and ignored the App.js/Index.js the first time around. I went through and was changing stuff over from es5 to es6 and also making my file structure better, and now the website seems to be broken at certain a certain threshold and I can't figure out how or why.

At 768px it collapses the navbar when it isn't supposed to, and the font size doesn't seem to scale appropriately like it did before. Just not sure what to do here. Can link github files if i need to.

[image: img]

Comment: have you tried using your browsers 'inspect element'  to see what changes, and which css rules are being used?

Comment: @FrazerKirkman I sure have. Everything seems to be the exact same. Which is the most confusing part. I did notice that the container class, where it says "responsive front-end development" doesn't scale, and doesn't follow bootstrap's media query rule of changing sizes. So I'm thinking it might have something to do with bootstrap?

Comment: the red X looks like there is an error, you should check what that says.

Comment: Are you using react-bootstrap?

Comment: The red x is for "Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element." which hasn't really affected things in the past. I just imported react-bootstrap. Before i was using it like regular css.

Comment: If you are using `react-bootstrap` then sometimes you can't override its styles and for that you'll need to use [radium](https://www.npmjs.com/package/radium) to wrap your bootstrap component in it. Then you can apply styles. It also supports media-queries for inline styles.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I ultimately just ended up redoing all the font sizes.